# Impersonate user in Meteor

Tags: meteor, impersonation

I've built impersonate method in my Meteor application in order to login as another user, based on following article: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/impersonating-a-user. I also have Intercom integration (chat widget and user tracking). I would like to be able to disable on client side that Intercom widget, in order to avoid any tracking from Intercom application, when I am logged as another user (impersonating). I was thinking about creating on user profile impersonate boolean property, and updating it to true, when I am triggering that impersonate method for any user. The problem is that, I have no idea how to set it to false when impersonate method is finished. According to article, you can stop impersonating when you refresh the browser manually. Could you please help me, and find the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can solve this in two parts:

When we start impersonating a user, keep track of who is impersonating who. Let's do this by first extending the `impersonate` method in the tutorial:

```
Meteor.methods({
  impersonate: function(userId) {
    check(userId, String);

    if (!Meteor.users.findOne(userId))
      throw new Meteor.Error(404, 'User not found');
    if (!Meteor.user().isAdmin)
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Permission denied');

    Meteor.users.update(this.userId, { $set: { 'profile.impersonating': userId }});
    this.setUserId(userId);

  }
});
```

Next we need to listen for a new login (which should happen on a browser refresh)

```
Meteor.onLogin(() => {
  Meteor.call('clearImpersonation', (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log('Error clearing impersonation: ',err);
  });
});

Meteor.methods({
  clearImpersonation(){
    const user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    if (user && user.profile && user.profile.impersonating) Meteor.users.update(user._id,{ $unset: 'profile.impersonating' });
    return;
  }
});
```

Now in your UI you can disable Intercom by checking for the existence of `Meteor.user().profile.impersonating`

Comment: Hi Micheal, thanks for suggestion, but there seems to be problem with onConnection and Meteor.user() or Meteor.userId() methods. Both can be only invoked either in Meteor method calls or publications. When I use these methods in onConnection method I am getting following error:  Exception in onConnection callback: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls or publications.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I added a method to clear the impersonation.

Comment: Hi Micheal, this approach still does not work. Meteor.user(), this.userId and Meteor.userId() methods return null in clearImpersonation method.

Comment: Ah ok, realized that `onConnection` runs before the user is logged in. Changed this to `onLogin`

Comment: Thank you Micheal

Comment: change to if `(user && user.profile.impersonating)`